# Can't connect objects xcode 4.2

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I defined an `uitableviewcontroller` with static cells in Xcode 4.2 ,the problem is when i want to connect objects like buttons or txtfields to my headers automatically, when i push controls and drag line to code it says:

> Could not insert new outlet connection: no @implemention found for class   "uitableviewcontroller"

and then nothing, just this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it ,You can't define default classes ,so you have to define your own classes  and don't use the default classes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `.m` file in the project and that it has block starting with `@implementation` and ending with `@end`.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete the project folder which you are working on .

After that in Xcode , clean build and it worked fine .